# Exluding iphone 4S from supported devices by requiring armv7s

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, appstore-approval

I'm about to release a game, and I've decided the cut-off (for performance and aspect ratio reasons) is the iphone 5 on the bottom end. So no iphone 4s.

The only way to restrict devices is by using combinations of requirements in the UIRequredDeviceCapabilities key of info.plist.

Requiring armv7s restricts the right devices, based on this tool:

http://28byteslater.com/ios-compatibility/?exclude=&require=9#chart

BUT... there are conflicting reports on whether this is will work, and be accepted by the app store. Some articles say that if you require armv7s you HAVE to require armv7 as well. Does anyone actually tried submitting an app with an armv7s requirement to prevent iphone 4s downloads?

Comment: Questions regarding app-store approval are off-topic, however I believe that Apple will require you to support all devices that can run the base OS you are targeting, which means iPhone 4S

Comment: Did you get an answer for this?  We have the same problem.